# Hide Form/Show Div after jQuery Validation and onSubmit

Tags: jquery, validation, hide, show

I'm using Inline Form Validation Engine 1.6.4, which works fine, but I'd like to hide the form and show a message-containing div after the validation and submit.

Is there an easy way to incorporate something like the following code into jquery.validationEngine.js and have it fire only after successful validation and onSubmit?

```
function showHide(form) { 
    var serial = $(form).serialize();
    $.post(form.action, serial, function(){
        $('#formID').hide();
        $('#hidden_div').show();
    });
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you even looked through the documentation for such an event? If you mean the [jQuery Validation Engine](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine), then it is under [AJAX/Callbacks](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine#callbacks)

Comment: I really need an example of implementing onAjaxFormComplete to trigger the form hide and div show as part of the validation engine.

Comment: You need an example to hide a `div`? What is wrong with those in the jQuery docs? (`jQuery( '#myelem' ).hide();`) Or do you need an example on how to use the `onAjaxFormComplete` event hook? Well look at the example for the similar `onValidationComplete` event in the documentation linked above.